# I can´t scroll my jtable although i have a scrollpane

Tags: java, sql, jtable, jscrollpane, dao

what could be the reason that i cant scroll down my jtable? .. i also have a scrollPane.

i can see my table filled with data from the database, but i cant click on any row or scroll down or up why?

**CONTROLLER**

```
public void controllActionListenerShowEquipmentTable() {
    main.setActionListenerShowEquipmentTable(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
            if(action.getSource()== main.getShowEquipmentTable()){
                equ = new EquipmentDAO();
                try {
                    ResultSet re = equ.show();
                    main.showEquipmentTable(re);
                    main.showPanel("8");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

**MAIN**

```
public void showEquipmentTable(ResultSet res){
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10,84,645,402);
    scrollPane.setBackground(new Color (0,0,0,50));
    showEquipment.add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
}
```

**EQUIPMENT DAO CLASS IMPLEMENTS DAOINTERFACE**

```
public class EquipmentDAO implements DaoInterface{

private Connection con;
private java.sql.PreparedStatement sta;
private Statement std;
private ResultSet res;
private DatabaseHandler handle;
private String query;

@Override
public ResultSet show() throws SQLException{
    handle = new DatabaseHandler();
    Connection con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
    String query = "select EID as ID, EquipmentName as Name, EquipmentSection as Section, EquipmentType as Type, EquipmentValue as Value, EquipmentAmount as Amount from Equipment";
    sta = con.prepareStatement(query);
    res = sta.executeQuery(query);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code.It is difficult to tell what might be causing the issue.check whether you have set `table.setEnabled(false)` anywhere

Comment: my full code is really long ... like more than 1000 lines?... should i really put it in here? i mean would you check it? @Madhan

Comment: Put it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: - controller class: http://pastebin.com/DepMUJcp  mainframeclass: http://pastebin.com/R0tt9h71   EQUIPMENT DAO CLASS : http://pastebin.com/h7gWdD8W  .. SHOW EQUIPMENT CLASS : http://pastebin.com/1RbsNCbu   ...

Comment: @Madhan  the comment above i copied my code into pastebin :) thx for taking a look if you need a class tell me?

Comment: you are also not able to edit the data in the JTable right..

Comment: and try removing the scrollPane.setBounds(10,84,645,402);

Comment: i cant edit anything :/ ... when I click on a row nothing happens .. normaly i can click on a row and it will be lighten up blue r something so that you know that its clickedd right now ... :/ @Madhan

Comment: @madhan ... i deleted the line  scrollPane.setBounds(10,84,645,402); ... and now i cant even see anything in the table :/

Comment: ok dont remove that..and remove the `table = new JTable();
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane();` from `showAllCustomer` and `showEquipmentTable` methods in MainFrameSoftware class and put those two lines inside constructor.because there is no need to create a new object everytime

Comment: yeah you are right ... but still i cant scroll on my table or click on a row.. :/ @Madhan

Comment: and why are you setting .setLayout(null); for all panels

Comment: i made the panels with a windowbuilder @madhan .. i mean it cant be whats the difference between show all customer and show equipment.. because when i run the programm and go on the panel of show all customer and click on show table i see the entries, i can click on them and scroll up and down .. :/

Comment: So is it working now as you said *i can click on them and scroll up and down*

Comment: If you have solved your problem post that as an answer

Comment: @Madhan it is still not working :/ .. table is looking like this http://i.imgur.com/lPRSdvY.jpg   and this is how it should look like .. plus scrolling  http://i.imgur.com/216deyw.jpg

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069673/jtable-wont-scroll-in-jscrollpane)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115400/trying-to-get-a-jtable-jscrollpane-to-scroll)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  hey guys.. sry for tagging you but i read something about the other problems you solved and it was also about scrollpane and jtable.. so i wanted to ask you if you maybe know whats wrong ? ... thank you :)

Comment: @trashgod   sry for tagging you but i am really desperate about this problem :/

Comment: i solved the problem :) ... the problem was that i created two tables... one in my mainclass and added it into the mainframe .. but i just needed it on the class with the panel.. :) @Madhan